# AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create fragment slider with indicator that contains text inside.

I found some tutorial online that contains image slider and I've edited it to text slider, though I'm receiving this error message:

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Now I've checked my code and I used ViewGroup only once in MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager _mViewPager;
    private CalcsPagerAdapter _adapter;
    private ImageView _btn1, _btn2, _btn3;
    public MainFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setUpView();
        setTab();
        onCircleButtonClick();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
    private void onCircleButtonClick() {
        _btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
        _btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });
        _btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });
    }
    private void setUpView() {
        _mViewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.textviewPager);
        _adapter = new CalcsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getFragmentManager());
        _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
        _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        initButton();
    }
    private void setTab() {
        _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.holo_circle);
                _btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.holo_circle);
                _btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.holo_circle);
                btnAction(position);
            }
        });
    }
    private void btnAction(int action) {
        switch (action) {
            case 0:
                _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                break;
            case 1:
                _btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                break;
            case 2:
                _btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
                break;
        }
    }
    private void initButton() {
        _btn1 = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        _btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fill_circle);
        _btn2 = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        _btn3 = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    }
    private void setButton(Button btn, String text, int h, int w) {
        btn.setWidth(w);
        btn.setHeight(h);
        btn.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And I've also used it in each fragment java file (fragmentBmi.java for example):

```
public class fragmentBmi extends Fragment {


    public fragmentBmi() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container, false);
    }


}
```

As you can see I used it only once at onCreateView method.

How can I fix that ImageView cast issue to ViewGroup?

[Tutorial I've used](http://javaant.com/viewpager-with-circle-indicator-in-android/#.WRnUP_l97cu)

**EDIT**

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#32383d">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textviewPager" />
    <include layout="@layout/footer"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

mainactivity.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.none.myapplication.MainFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#00000000">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:src="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
                android:src="@drawable/holo_circle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
                    android:src="@drawable/holo_circle"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                </ImageView>
            </ImageView>
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And there is also xml for each fragment but it only contains text view so it useless to my question.

Comment: post your layout code...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 edited.

Comment: post your `footer`...layout code

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end your `ImageView` tag: in `footer.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/holo_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
            android:src="@drawable/holo_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"
            android:src="@drawable/holo_circle" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The exception occurs as you are putting images under your imageview tag

As `imageview` is not a `ViewGroup` like `Linearlayout` you can not put multiple elements under it.